# How to check if username already registered

Tags: php, if-statement

My `else if`  is not working correctly. Can you show me where I have made a mistake and explain how it works? Thank you!

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if(strlen($password)<6){
            exit ('Password must contain 6 symbols');
        }

        $password = md5($password);
        $query ="INSERT INTO register(username,first_name,last_name,email,phone,password) VALUES ('$username', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone', '$password')"
        or die(mysqli_error($connect));

        if($result=mysqli_query($connect,$query)) {
            echo '<h3><font color="red">You have successfully registered</font></h3>';
        }else if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) {
            exit("Username already exists");
        }
    } 

?>
```

Comment: The `or die` should be at the end of the `mysqli_query` line, not the string assignment.

Comment: In addition to Barmar's answer: You never handling database errors, like you produced with your query, so else if is working fine, but you don't have the else branch :)

Comment: dont make sense having a `num_rows` on insertions

Comment: This code has serious SQL injection issues - please fix before going live. (I've removed the request to fix your code - this is probably why you were downvoted - we are happy to help here, but we won't do people's work for them. Worth bearing in mind for your next question!)

Comment: @Styphon No, this does not belong on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks, that's a handy link. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_num_rows()` can only be used with `SELECT` queries, it returns the number of rows in the result set.

To test how many rows were affected by a modification query, use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php). And the argument to this should be `$connect`, not `$result` (which is just a boolean).

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die (mysqli_error($connect));
} elseif (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 0) {
    exit ("Username already exists");
} else {
    echo '<h3><font color="red">You have successfully registered</font></h3>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if($result) {
    echo '<h3><font color="red">You have successfully registered</font></h3>';
}else {
    exit("Username already exists");
}
```

So you run your query with the first instruction and then assign the result of the query to $result. Next you check if $result exitsts. If yes you have inserted the user. If not the user is duplicated. You don't need to add an if statement to the else to do this check.